# Java graphics paint method execution flow

Tags: java, class, action, paint, abstract

I came across this code. I thought I alleviate this confusion before I run into any hiccups along the way in programming. I am having trouble understanding whether the paint or the actionPerformed method gets executed first in Board class. I hope my java comments are correctly stated.

The thing is, I took introductory Java in the summer and graphics was only introduced towards the end of the course. The class used ImageIcon and we never touched the drawImage method and Image abstract class. I also do not understand the paint method at all. This code is more involved than the Java graphics lecture I had. Based on the Java API, the paint method originated from the JComponent class which is JPanel's superclass.

So what is this parameter Graphics g that the paint method takes in all about and how should I think about it? How does the paint method know which object of a graphics class to paint. I looked at the Java API and it says Graphics is an abstract class. How can g be an object if its data type is abstract? I am saying g is an object because the code is calling the drawImage method on the object g.

On a side note, does repaint method mean erase the content in the JPanel and redraw the entire component like rendering?

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

private Image apple;
private int apple_x;
private int apple_y;

// over-riding the paint method from the JComponent Class
public void paint(Graphics g){
                // recursively call the paint method
                super.paint(g);

                g.drawImage(apple, apple_x, apple_y, this); 
    }

 // does this method gets called first or the top one?
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



        repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: I think that most of what you're asking and important points that you've yet to ask (but will) can be answered here: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: Note that you should be overriding `paintComponent(...)` not `paint(...)`. Note that `repaint()` only suggests to the paint manager that the GUI should be painted and is not always followed by a call to paint(...) especially if paint calls get "stacked". And repaint() erases nothing. It's the super paint(...) or `paintComponent(...)` call that does any erasing.

Comment: what is the different between former and the latter? the paintComponent says it will call the paint method. Why this extra process?

Comment: please read the link. You'll see that paintComponent does not call paint! More like visa versa. Also read what it says about double buffering.

Comment: thanks for the link. I will read it with great care!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing in Java (and basically all current windowing systems) follows the Hollywood principle:

> You don't call me; I call you.

I.e. you can tell the system that a certain area will need to be redrawn (`repaint()`). But you'll have to wait until the system calls you to do the drawing. In Java, the system will call the `paint()` method and will pass you a `Graphics` instance to use for drawing.

So the order of event is:

1. `actionPerformed()`
2. `paint()`

`Graphics` is often called a graphics context. It's an object used for drawing. Depending on the system and the current requirements, the drawing might go directly on the screen or into an offscreen buffer that is later copied to the screen. The `Graphics` instance takes care of the details.

Comment: when you mean system, do you mean the operating system or the Java Virtual Machine?

Comment: @Nicholas: The operating system and the Java UI libraries tightly interact with each other. So it's not always possible to say who initiated an action. The overall architecture I've described is followed by all operating system with a windowing concept (that I know of). So it's mainly the operating system.

Comment: The API says Graphics is an abstract class so I am baffled that there can be an instance of an abstract class.

Comment: @Nicholas: Yes, `Graphics` is an abstract class. But the parameter of the `paint()` method will contain an instance of a concrete class, which is a subclass of `Graphics`.

Comment: @Nicholas You may find [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) of interest

Answer (score 1):

Someone can correct me if I am wrong.

Yes, graphics is an abstract class. But an instance of any class that inherits Graphics (such as Graphics2D) can be passed as graphics. If I recall correctly this is call upcasting. g is passed by the UI thread that called paint(), either because the object was invalidated, or has to be updated.

The graphics object is a reference to the actual bitmap that appears to the user.

Comment: Graphics object is not a reference to the viewed image but can be thought of as pen with which you can draw on the viewed image. Also, I think that Java *down-casts* when putting a Graphics2D object into a Graphics variable, but I'm a little rusty on that aspect.